# giving signals to other processes

Tags: c

I am writing a shell that needs to be able to restart a stopped process if the user inputs a certain command.

My question is: which system call do I use to be able to give the signal of SIGCONT to the proper pid/pgid?

Comment: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`kill(pid, SIGCONT)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/kill/)